# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException while HttpsURLConnection from java code

Tags: java, http, https, connection

I have a simple java code that just open a HttpsURLConnection which produces SSLHandshakeException but the link https://www.zlti.com is accessing fine when open in browser and only through code, facing the SSLHandshakeException.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String url = "https://www.zlti.com";
    HttpsURLConnection huc = null;        
    try {
    huc = (HttpsURLConnection)(new URL(url).openConnection());
    huc.getResponseCode();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

The full stack trace as

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
at Automate.BrokenLinks.main(BrokenLinks.java:29)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)

Comment: No, there the user itself is hosting the site and trying and access. For me, this link i can able to view from browser https://www.zlti.com, but unable to access from java code. Wondering why unable to access from java code and throws SSLHandshakeExcpetion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked after adding the below piece of code

```
try {
    SSLContext ssl_ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManager[ ] trust_mgr = new TrustManager[ ] {
    new X509TrustManager() {
       public X509Certificate[ ] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
       public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[ ] certs, String t) { }
       public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[ ] certs, String t) { }
     }
  };
        ssl_ctx.init(null,                // key manager
                     trust_mgr,           // trust manager
                     new SecureRandom()); // random number generator
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ssl_ctx.getSocketFactory());
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```